# What's the effect of empty macro `GRPCAPI` before gRPC function declaration?

Tags: c, grpc-c++

When I read the code in gRPC, I found many APIs using `GRPCAPI` as qualifier.

```cpp
GRPCAPI grpc_channel* grpc_cronet_secure_channel_create(
    void* engine, const char* target, const grpc_channel_args* args,
    void* reserved);
```

When I click the link to `GRPCAPI`, it's an empty macro.

```cpp
#ifndef GPRAPI
#define GPRAPI
#endif

#ifndef GRPCAPI
#define GRPCAPI GPRAPI
#endif
```

I understand some usages of empty macro:

- preventing multiple copies of the same header being included
- used as a switch for debug or removing sensitive code

But here the `GRPCAPI` belongs to neither. Is it just a marker to tell us the function is an API? Or more effect for document or others functions?

Comment: Likely there are platform-specific definitions as well, for dllimport/dllexport/__attribute__((visibility))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really appreciate the answer from @Raildex and comment from @paulsm4, which are very inspiring.

But the exactly function of `GRPCAPI` and `GPRAPI` is used to mark APIs as a label.

There is a script in grpc named [list_api.py](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/tools/buildgen/plugins/list_api.py) using the label GPRAPI and GRPCAPI, which is the only place using these two labels.

```py
_RE_API = r'(?:GPRAPI|GRPCAPI|CENSUSAPI)([^;]*);'

for m in re.finditer(_RE_API, text):   # match file content
...
```

After running the script, we'll get:

```
...
- arguments: void* engine, const char* target, const grpc_channel_args* args, void*
    reserved
  header: include/grpc/grpc_cronet.h
  name: grpc_cronet_secure_channel_create
  return_type: grpc_channel*
...
```

Answer (score 3):

Its either for platform specific attributes or for future attributes.

For Windows DLLs, you usually specify
`__declspec(dllexport)` when **compiling the library** and
`__declspec(dllimport)` when **consuming the library**.

A macro is the convenient way to both compile and consume it because you only define the value of the macro to be `__declspec(dllexport)`/`__declspec(dllimport)` within the header.
the same goes for other compiler attributes, such as `__attribute__(visibility(default))`/`__attribute__(visibility(hidden))` on GCC

Now when the library is statically linked, you don't need all that and you define the macro to have no value.
An example would be:

```
#ifdef STATIC_LIBRARY
     #define LIBRARY_API 
#else
#ifdef LIBRARY_EXPORTS
#    define LIBRARY_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#    define LIBRARY_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif


LIBRARY_API void foo(); // when statically linked, it's a simple void function. If dynamically linked, it's either dllexport when compiling the library or dllimport when consuming it.
```

Another explanation can be a calling convention modifier.
x86 (I only know x86) has different calling conventions - these decide how the caller/callee treats parameters of functions on the assembly level.

Something like this:

```
#if WIN32
#define APICALL cdecl
#else
#define APICALL 
#endif

APICALL void foo() // uses cdecl on WIN32
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but this macro mentioned in the question seems not related to the windows library. There is another macro `GPR_EXPORT` seems doing that.

Comment: @JasonPan in this case it can also be a calling convention modifier.
x86 processors allow different calling conventions (`stdcall`, `cdecl`, `fastcall` etc.).

Comment: @Raildex - you're absolutely correct: "It's either for platform specific attributes or for future attributes." Your examples illustrate why this makes sense.  Furthermore, the file the OP cited happens to be named "[port_platform.h](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/include/grpc/impl/codegen/port_platform.h)"  GRPCAPI is simply available to be expanded to other, non-empty values to "decorate" function declarations as needed for other platforms/other environments/other purposes.